# Annotating colorbar of a matplotlib.basemap plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

[image]The following code will plot what I wish to see, but I was wondering how to edit the colorbar so that it has a title?

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
x = []
y = []
z = []
with open('TEMP.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="\t")
    for row in plots:
        x.append(float(row[0]))
        y.append(float(row[1]))
        z.append(float(row[2]))
m = Basemap(projection='stere',lat_ts = -25, lat_0 = -25.27 , lon_0 = 133.77, resolution='l',width=14000000, height=10000000)

m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-80, 80, 20))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180, 181, 20))
m.fillcontinents(color='coral')
lats = x
lons = y
time = z
x, y = m(lons,lats)
sc = m.scatter(x,y,60,z,cmap='jet',marker='o')
plt.colorbar(sc)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `...how to edit the colorbar so that it has a color bar...` What do you mean by this? I think you accidentally typed this. What do you want? Title on your color bar? Custom ticks on your colorbar? Textbox pointing to your colorbar?

Comment: Apologies.  I meant to write title.

Comment: ah, it makes sense now =). You can use [colorbar.set_label()](https://matplotlib.org/api/colorbar_api.html#matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase.set_label). `cb = plt.colorbar(sc) cb.set_label('foo')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different ways you can do this. This first is as suggested by @umutto in the comments which is using `set_label`. The second is using `ax.set_title`, however there are some differences in the default position of the labels.

```
plt.imshow(np.random.randn(25).reshape(5,5))

cb = plt.colorbar() 

cb.set_label("Test 1", rotation=270)
cb.ax.set_title("Test 2")

plt.show()
```

This produces the following figure:

[image]

Comment: Thanks David.  Those lines produce exactly what I was looking for.  Cheers.